# How do I convert this JSON data into this URL format?

Tags: python, json, urllib

I am trying to convert this data into a URL format (I don't know the technical terms for that but I think you get the idea what am I asking)
This the Body data:

```
body = {
        'dont-ask-for-email': 0,
        'action': 'submit_user_review',
        'post_id': 61341,
        'email': '',
        'subscribe': 1,
        'previous_hosting_id': '',
        'fb_token': '',
        'title': 'I suggest you guys to add more services',
        'summary': 'So far, so good. Quick response, better prices and effective support. All a com>
        'score_reliability': 10,
        'score_pricing': 10,
        'score_userfriendly': 10,
        'score_support': 10,
        'score_features': 10,
        'hosting_type': 'dedicated-server',
        'author': 'Andrew McCarthy',
        'social_link': '',
        'site': '',
        'screenshot[image][]': '',
        'screenshot[description][]': '',
        'user_data_process_agreement': 1,
        'user_email_popup': '',
        'subscribe_popup': 1,
        'email_asked': 0
}
```

I need this format to run my python script

```
jsondata = 'dont-ask-for-email=0&action=submit_user_review&post_id=61341&email=&subscribe=1&previous_hosting_id=&fb_token=&title=I+suggest+you+guys+to+add+more+services&summary=So+far,+so+good.+Quick+response,+better+prices+and+effective+support.+All+a+company+needs,+they+got+it.&score_reliability=10&score_pricing=10&score_userfriendly=10&score_support=10&score_features=10&hosting_type=dedicated-server&author=Manik+Lal&social_link=&site=&screenshot%5Bimage%5D%5B%5D=&screenshot%5Bdescription%5D%5B%5D=&user_data_process_agreement=1&user_email_popup=&subscribe_popup=1&email_asked=1'
```

I tried dumping it with

```
jsondata = json.dumps(body)
```

When i `print(jsondata)` after running the code, I get the exact same format.

Is there any library or method to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `urllib.parse.urlencode` method to encode a dictionary as an url argument string:

```
import urllib.parse
encoded = urllib.parse.urlencode(body)
# encoded = 'dont-ask-for-email=0&action=submit_user_review&post_id=6134 ... '
```

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot and get back to you in a minute

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is converting the json to querystring.

Using [`jsonurl`](https://pypi.org/project/jsonurl/):

```
import jsonurl    
d = {"one" : 1, "two" : 2}    
print(jsonurl.query_string(d))   # one=1&two=2
```

**EDIT**:

Without using any builtin or 3PL:

```
body = {
        'dont-ask-for-email': 0,
        'action': 'submit_user_review',
        }            

query_str = ''
for key in body.keys():
    query_str += str(key) + '=' + str(body[key]) + "&"

print(query_str[:-1])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
action=submit_user_review&dont-ask-for-email=0
```

Comment: The other answer uses a builtin.

Comment: Ha, indeed. I will try adding other alternatives as well ^^

Comment: Your second without using any built-in does not perform the actual encoding - it will give the wrong result for any values containing characters that have special meanings in urls - such as `&` and `+`. Use the built-in, it handles these special cases.